# visibility_of_element_located or element_to_be_clickable - Final solution?

Tags: python, selenium, visibility

I read a little about the functions of checking in selenium whether an element is visible on the page (for the user) so that he can hover or click on this element.
We have options:

**1.visibility_of_element_located**

An expected condition for checking that, element is located by locator present in the DOM, and element  is visible on a web page. **Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.**

**2.element_to_be_clickable**

Wait for an element identified by the locator is enabled and visible such that you can click on it. Note that element should be in visible state

**And here's the question.**

I have a page:
https://tvn24.pl/
in which I have to hover over the Element

```
"button.account-standard__toggle-button"
```

that the "frame" unfolds.
In which I have to click on the element `

```
"div.account-standard__popup button.account-content__button.account-content__button--large"
```

I would like the click to happen after waiting for the element to be visible to the user - which is only possible after hovering over the first element But :

What if the second button, even though I did not hit the first button, is in the DOM and already has a height and width greater than 0.
The condition will be met even though the user will not actually see it.
Isn't the second way (element_to_be_clickable) better in this case?.

What about the situation when the mouse hover occurs, but for some reason the expanded frame disappears / collapses or something else before selenium finds and clicks on the second button.

Below, there is a screen with hovering the button (upper right corner - a button imitating a human) and below, an expanded frame with a "log in" button
Selection in the inspection is in the second button that appears after hovering over the previous one.
And these graphic values ​​are constant all the time, they do not change whether I hover the mouse on the first button or not.
Unless I have something wrong with this development tool

[image]

I wrote this codes before.
But I am afraid that it does not predict that, for example, when you hover over the first button, something will load on the page and the expandable element will disappear before the driver finds the second button and clicks.
I know I can use "wait.untill (ec.visible ...) but I want to avoid a possible time exception.
As you can see in this picture, when we hover on button 1, in the highest div for this Li it appears in the class name "--visible"

```
def move_to_login_page_from_main_page(driver):
wait = WebDriverWait

CSS_account = "button.account-standard__toggle-button"
CSS_login = "div.account-standard__popup button.account-content__button.account-content__button--large"
CSS_roll_out_frame = "div.account-standard--visible"
expected_url = "account.tvn.pl"

attempts = 0
while attempts <= 10:

    account = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_account)
    ac(driver).move_to_element(account).perform()
    roll_out_frames = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_roll_out_frame)

    if len(roll_out_frames) > 0:
        log_in_button = roll_out_frames.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_login)
        ac(driver).move_to_element(log_in_button).click(log_in_button).perform()
        wait(driver, 10, 1).until(ec.url_contains(expected_url))
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        attempts += 1







def move_to_login_page_from_main_page2(driver):
wait = WebDriverWait

CSS_account = "button.account-standard__toggle-button"
CSS_login = "div.account-standard__popup button.account-content__button.account-content__button--large"
expected_url = "account.tvn.pl"

attempts = 0
while attempts <= 10:

    account = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_account)
    ac(driver).move_to_element(account).click(account).perform()
    login_button = driver.find_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_login))

    if login_button.is_enabled():
        ac(driver).move_to_element(login_button).click(login_button).perform()
        wait(driver, 10, 1).until(ec.url_contains(expected_url))
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        attempts += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This code shows different conditions of your element:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

base_url = 'https://tvn24.pl/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=rf"chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(base_url)

cookie_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
cookie_button.click()

CSS_account = "button.account-standard__toggle-button"
login_xpath = '//div[@class="account-standard__popup"]//button[@class="account-content__button account-content__button--large"]'


def check_elem_state(xpath):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, login_xpath)))
        print('Element present')
    except:
        print('Sorry - not present')

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, login_xpath)))
        print('Element visible')
    except:
        print('Sorry - not visible')

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, login_xpath)))
        print('Element clickable')
    except:
        print('Sorry - not clickable')


print('-------Without slider--------')
check_elem_state(login_xpath)
login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, login_xpath)
print("Login is displayed: ", login.is_displayed())

print('-------Showing slider-------')
account = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_account)
AC(driver).move_to_element(account).click(account).perform()

check_elem_state(login_xpath)
print("Login is displayed: ", login.is_displayed())
login.click()
```

The output:

```
-------Without slider--------
Element present
Sorry - not visible
Sorry - not clickable
Login is displayed:  False
-------Showing slider-------
Element present
Element visible
Element clickable
Login is displayed:  True
```

This way you can check if is both visible and clickable and perform any action if you close the `wait` in try expect.

Only remark here is to use proper expected exception - in example any exception will be caught so you need add proper exception.

Edit:
In console you can check it this way:

```
function isVisible(elem) {
    if (!(elem instanceof Element)) throw Error('DomUtil: elem is not an element.');
    const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
    if (style.display === 'none') {console.log('display'); return false;}
    if (style.visibility !== 'visible') {console.log('visibility'); return false;}
    if (style.opacity < 0.1) {console.log('opacity'); return false;}
    if (elem.offsetWidth + elem.offsetHeight + elem.getBoundingClientRect().height +
        elem.getBoundingClientRect().width === 0) {
        console.log('client'); return false;
    }
    const elemCenter   = {
        x: elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + elem.offsetWidth / 2,
        y: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + elem.offsetHeight / 2
    };
    if (elemCenter.x < 0) {console.log('x<0'); return false;}
    if (elemCenter.x > (document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth)) {console.log('width'); return false;}
    if (elemCenter.y < 0) {console.log('y<0'); return false;}
    if (elemCenter.y > (document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight)) {console.log('height'); return false;}
    let pointContainer = document.elementFromPoint(elemCenter.x, elemCenter.y);
    do {
        if (pointContainer === elem) {console.log('point continter'); return true;} else { console.log(pointContainer)}
    } while (pointContainer = pointContainer.parentNode);
    return false;
}
```

And trigger function:

```
isVisible(document.getElementsByClassName('account-content__button--large')[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

### your locator locator for the dropdown element is not unique it is detecting some other element , use :

Now if you use visibility of dropdown content without clicking the dropdown button it will time out.

```
driver.get('https://tvn24.pl/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                 '#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                  ".account-standard__toggle-button"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class="account-standard__popup"] button[class="account-content__button account-content__button--large"]')))
```

**This will first wait for accept cookies and then click ok , then click hover button , and then click the displayed dropdown button**

## Strategy to find unique locator:

If you are not able to get a unique property for an element then find an unique sibling or parent or child and refrence the element to it

In this case :

```
 [class="account-standard__popup"]
```

this parent element is unique refrence you can use to uniquely locate the child element :

```
button[class="account-content__button account-content__button--large"]
```

## **To answer your question:**

See the is_clickable method. you can see that it will first check for visibilty.
So if use you element_is_visible, it won't check for is_enabled() else it will check if the button is enabled, meaning it will ensure that the button or element doesn't **have the disabled html attribute**

**IF the button is enabled or disabled using css class** and not  using HTML disabled attribute, then there is no difference between using visibility and clicakable,

As is_Enabled will not check for element disabled state through css but only through html disable attribute.

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: But.... what about :

What if the second button, even though I did not hit the first button, is in the DOM and already has a height and width greater than 0. The condition will be met even though the user will not actually see it. Isn't the second way (element_to_be_clickable) better in this case?.

Comment: @ŁukaszGil added the explanation for your question

Comment: I didn't mention a small detail: 
All this element is found in the element "div.account-standard.account-standard-low"
When you hover over ".account-standard__toggle-button", the dropdown element expands and this div becomes "div.account-standard.account-standard-low--visible".